# Guide "Serving Web Content with Spring MVC" compiles, but don't works

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am working on an iMac 10.10, with Java 1.8.0 and Maven 3.2.5.
The example at the title ("https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/)" compiles but does not work, using the Maven build.

I always get this runtime error invoking localhost:8080/greeting:

```
'org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "greeting"'
```

I tried some investigation; followed the hint at the previous question at [Deployment of resources on embedded Tomcat server using Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20917008/deployment-of-resources-on-embedded-tomcat-server-using-spring-boot); I've tried to use more recent versions (1.2.1.RELEASE), with no change.

```
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>0.5.0.M6</version>
....
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
<version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
```

I also reverted back to 0.5.0.M6, using versioning on the thymeleaf POM section
and I am now getting a `Circular viewpath [greeting]` error. But I also understand that I am going back to a version of Spring-boot that does not support many of the annotation features.

Any hints? I'd like to get the example compiled and to go on further.

Comment: Did you download the code from github? The parent being at 0.5.0 looks like it could be a problem to me, and I doubt that came from the published source code.

Comment: Solved. I'm sorry, it was a typo and downloading from github solved the issue. Thank you and excuse me.